# How can I get tagged_places of my friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.3, graph-api-explorer

When I submit a get on Graph API Explorer, like that:

```
me?fields=tagged_places
```

Works good and return the data of my 'tagged places' to me.

But when I try to get 'tagged places' of my friends, I got this error message:

> "error": {
>           "message": "(#100) Unknown fields: tagged_places.", 
>           "type": "OAuthException", 
>           "code": 100

I want to know if is not possible to get 'tagged_places' of my friends or Im doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have the permission of the item you were tagged in.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130806/facebook-graph-api-tagged-places-returns-empty-array/27233145#27233145).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly note that the field 'tagged_places' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants the 'user_tagged_places' permission.

This means 
1. Your app should request for the 'user_tagged_places' permission during login
2. Your friends should approve of this request while signing into the app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already requested permission and my friend already approved, and still showing error message: **"error": { "message": "(#100) Unknown fields: tagged_places.", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100**